# SQL Multi-table update syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, database-schema

My goal is to set the formulaId column of tblWosampleTest equal to the value of the formulaid column of tbltest where tblwoSampleTest and tbltest have the same testid.  TblTest is a sort of glossary containing information on every testid.  Each record has a unique testid and also a formulaid column that contains the formulaid for that specific testid.  I assigned values to these formulaids but realized they did not appear also in tblwosampletest so I am writing a script to translate the formulaid changes to the tblWosampletest table. tblWosampletest is a table containing all the work orders completed.  Each record is unique by a combination of its WOID, sampleID and testid columns.  The testid column indicates what test was done for the work order.  There is also a formulaid column.  This formulaid column is important to be updated because tblWosampletest is the record source of a subform table and needs to correctly display what the formulaid of that particular work order was.  Here is the code I came up with.  I am not very good at SQL so I would like someone to tell me if I got the logic correct.

```
UPDATE tblWOSampleTest

JOIN tblTest t1
ON tblWOSampleTest.TestID=t1.TestID 
WHERE tblWOSampleTest.TestID=t1.TestID 

SET tblWOSampleTest.FormulaID = tbltest.formulaID
```

Does this make sense and achieve what I am trying to do?  Here are two pictures of portions of the tables for reference.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for a multi-table UPDATE can be a bit odd, I find this is easiest to follow:

```
UPDATE 
    t
SET
    t.FormulaID = t1.formulaID
FROM
   tblWOSampleTest t
   INNER JOIN tblTest t1 ON t1.TestID = t.TestID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query were almoust correct but it has a syntax error. The where clause should stay at the end of the query although in your example is not really needed since you are already using `ON` to have a correct link between the tables. You can also use table alias prepended to columns name.

```
UPDATE tblWOSampleTest t
INNER JOIN tblTest t1
ON t.TestID = t1.TestID 
SET t.FormulaID = t1.formulaID
```